# I need to run a single selenium script by providing the script path to jenkins job. is this possible

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a single selenium script by providing the script path to Jenkins job. is this possible ?

I am also connecting the Jenkins job to GIT repo. and fetch code fron GIT and then run a single script

I have configured a JOB and have successfully connected the job to GIT repo using Jenkins.

Currently if i create a maven project from Jenkins job i can pass the pom.xml file to run. But i wants to pass a script path to Jenkins job and then run it.

Is this possible please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible to run single selenium script by providing the script path to Jenkins job.

Follow below steps to perform your task.

For adding the batch file follow the below steps:

1) Go to the Jenkins dashboard, create a new job in Jenkins

2) Click on new item and enter the item name and check the freestyle project radio button

a new job in Jenkins

3) Click Advance options

advance options

4) Click on use custom workspace and give your Selenium script project workspace path: “E:\Automation_workspace\Demo-testNG”

use custom workspace

5) Then go to Build and Select option from drop down box, execute your build through Windows batch command

6) And give your batch file name here – “run.bat”

run.bat command

7) Click on apply and save

8) Click on build now and see the build result on console output

Took steps from below link, if site gets expired/outdated still others can find steps here in post.
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Thank you for the reply .. I tried this and it is working for me now.